# Custom price.phtml file for product view template - Magento

Tags: php, magento

How can I create a custom price.phtml file and display it in a product view page?

Use case: I have updated the price.phtml file under product > view to add rich snippets / structured data, and I would like to create a new price.phtml file so that I can use it for 'Related Products' which appear on the product view page.

- Magento EE v 1.12

Comment: You will probably get a better response to this one at the Magento stack - http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Answer offered. http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3630/5

Comment: Could you please go through the updated question http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3630/5,  thank you.